# jQuery selector to capture class inside php if statement

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to make a selector to capture click events on code below :

index.php :

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <?php

    if ($page > 1) {
      $link = $page - 1;
      $prev = '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="'.$link.','.$record_per_page.'">Previous</a></li>';
    }else{
      $prev = '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a></li>';
    }

    $num = '';

    for($i = 1; $i<=$total_pages ; $i++){
      if($i == $page){
        $num .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
      }else{
        $num .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="'.$i.','.$record_per_page.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
      }
    }

    if ($page < $total_pages) {
      $link = $page + 1;
      $next = '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="'.$link.','.$record_per_page.'">Next</a></li>';
    }else{
      $next = '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a></li>';
    }

    echo $prev.$num.$next;

  ?>
</ul>
```

script.js :

```
$(document).on('click','.page-link',function () {
console.log('aaaaaa');
});
```

I already tried codes above, but it doesn't work, the console.log never showed up, is there any problem with my php code or jquery code ?

Comment: can you post html generated by your php code ?

Comment: Try this while testing: `$(document).on('click','.page-link',function (e) { e.preventDefault();
console.log('aaaaaa');
});`

Comment: @Swati these are the output : <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a></li><li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="1">1</a></li>

Comment: @mplungjan i tried that code, and nothing happened

Comment: did you add jquery cdn ? Also does your browser console shows any error?

Comment: @Ritesh Khandekar oh thanks mannn, it works , but would you please explain why the page-item instead page-link ?

Comment: @Swati yes already, and console log didn't show any error mesage

Comment: Try:`$(document).on('click','ul li .page-link',function() {
console.log('aaaaaa');
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all , and especially for **Ritesh Khandekar**, who gave me this code to solve my problem :

```
$(document).on('click','ul li .page-item',function() { console.log('aaaaaa'); });
```

I don't know why using *page-item* instead of *page-link*, but it workssss !!!!